# Python script to write(+lock) / read a file in Azure

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-storage-account

Iam new to python programming and Azure.

I need to write a script which will be executed by 2 processes.

The 2 processes will run the same python script. 
I know that Azure has storageAccounts to put some files in it, i've found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.fileservice?view=azure-python

and:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python

Here is some pseudo code to illustrate what i need to achieve:

```
function useStorageFile
   if(fileFromStorage == null)
      createFileInStorage lockFileInStorage;
      executeDockerCommand;
      writeResultOFCommandInStorageFile;
   else
      if(fileFromStorage != null)
        X:if(fileFromStorage.status !== 'locked')
           readResultFromFile
        else
           wait 1s;
           continue X;
```

Is it possible to lock/unlock a file in Azure? How can i achieve that in python for example? thank you.

**EDIT**
I have managed to write a file in Blob Storage with a python script. The question now is: How can i lock the file while writing the command result in it by the first process, and make it read by the second process as soon as the Blob Storage lock (if the option exists...) is released by the first process ? here is the python script iam using  :

```
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess

def run_sample():
    try:
        # Create the BlockBlockService that is used to call the Blob service for the storage account
        block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='xxxxxx', account_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

        # Create a container called 'quickstartblobs'.
        container_name ='quickstartblobs'
        block_blob_service.create_container(container_name)

        # Set the permission so the blobs are public.
        block_blob_service.set_container_acl(container_name, public_access=PublicAccess.Container)

        # Create a file in Documents to test the upload and download.
        local_path=os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)
        local_file_name ='youss.txt'
        full_path_to_file =os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)

        # Write text to the file.
        file = open(full_path_to_file,  'w')
        file.write("Hello, World!")
        file.close()

        print("Temp file = " + full_path_to_file)
        print("\nUploading to Blob storage as blob" + local_file_name)

        # Upload the created file, use local_file_name for the blob name
        block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, local_file_name, full_path_to_file)

        # List the blobs in the container
        print("\nList blobs in the container")
        generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
        for blob in generator:
            print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)

        # Download the blob(s).
        # Add '_DOWNLOADED' as prefix to '.txt' so you can see both files in Documents.
        full_path_to_file2 = os.path.join(local_path, str.replace(local_file_name ,'.txt', '_DOWNLOADED.txt'))
        print("\nDownloading blob to " + full_path_to_file2)
        block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name, local_file_name, full_path_to_file2)

        sys.stdout.write("Sample finished running. When you hit <any key>, the sample will be deleted and the sample "
                         "application will exit.")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        input()

        # Clean up resources. This includes the container and the temp files
        block_blob_service.delete_container(container_name)
        os.remove(full_path_to_file)
        os.remove(full_path_to_file2)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


# Main method.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_sample()
```

Comment: Do you have to use Azure File Storage? Can you use Azure Blob Storage instead?

Comment: @GauravMantri  no i said Azure File Storage because i am new to Azure and it was the first one i've found. Is Blob Storage better ? Is it possible to acheive my problem ? thanks

Comment: Thanks! One more question: Do you want to lock a file for writing or reading?

Comment: @GauravMantri i've used Blob Storage and manage to write a python script to create a file. My issue is actually to make sure that only one of the 2 processes (actually 2 VMs) will write in it and the second one read this file as soon as the lock is released. i will edit my question to write the code i've made to create the file in Blob Storage

Comment: I don't think you can lock file itself anyhow. How about emulating lock by creating second "lock" file in same folder with another name? The process before opening the actual file will check if there's lock file in folder, and if there's not - push the lock file, and then open the actual for reading, removing the lock file once the work is done. Obviously, there's a case of race condition possible, which can be theoretically resolved by using systems with much smaller latencies like RabbitMQ/Kafka queues or something based of semaphore technique.

Comment: @dimon222 the thing the same code will be run in 2 differents VM (so 2 different processes) within the same subnet (azure). And i think there is a way to achieve that with blob storage because i found this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-concurrency. I just need to find how :)

Comment: I mean the lock file to be managed on Azure File Storage (since its the storage that I assume you share via mount between two VMs). Honestly, most of these storage mechanisms are using eventual consistency, so for small latency you probably want to manage the concurrency outside of it via queues. Alternatively, If you use Azure Blob Storage instead, the file will only be commited to bucket when its completely uploaded(aka on commit). You can integrate event of file upload/commit to [Azure Functions](https://github.com/lbugnion/sample-azure-general/blob/master/Doc/functions-blob.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i lock the file while writing the command result in it by the
>   first process, and make it read by the second process as soon as the
>   Blob Storage lock (if the option exists...) is released by the first
>   process ?

Azure Blob Storage has a feature called [`Lease`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob) that you can make use of. Essentially `Leasing` process acquires an exclusive lock on the resource (blob in your case) and only one process can acquire lease on a blob. Once lease is acquired on the blob, any other process can't modify or delete the blob.

So what you would need to do is try to acquire a lease on the blob before writing. If the blob is already leased you will get an error back (HTTP Status Code 412, PreConditionFailed error). Assuming you don't get an error, you can continue with updating the file. Once the file is updated, you can either manually release the lock (either break lease or release lease) or let the lease auto expire. Assuming you get an error, you should wait and fetch the blob's lease status periodically (say every 5 seconds). Once you find that the blob is not leased anymore, you can read the blob's contents.

Comment: thanks man, it really looks like what i need, iam going to try your solution as it sounds like the ONE :) , Do you think it is feasible in python ?  thanks a lot

Comment: Leasing blob should be available in Storage SDK for python. Try looking for function `lease_blob` or something like this in blob_service.

Comment: i have found this for a python implementation  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-python-getting-started/blob/master/blob_advanced_samples.py 
How do you recommend to implement the fetch of the blob's lease periodically ? i imagine with a while loop probably (iam new to python programming sorry)

Comment: `How do you recommend to implement the fetch of the blob's lease periodically ?` - What I would do is get the blob's properties periodically and check the lease status. I am also not very conversant with python but yes, you will need to do a while loop.

Comment: Also, please make sure that you don't set `infinite` lease on the blob. Set it to a shorter duration (between 15 - 60 seconds) so that in case there's an issue with the process writing to the blob, the lease gets automatically cleared after that duration.